cmd - T typesets chapter files instead of root file?
I'm currently working with a root file and many chapters in Texshop. The chapters are in a sub-folder 'chapter'. I read in this pdf that you can actually insert the magic command % !TEX root = ../diss_chemie.tex (diss_chemie is my root) and use cmd-T to typeset the root instead of the chapter. Well, it doesn't work for me. Any suggestions?
edit: I added the magic command to the kap_01.tex (chapter) and \include{chapter/kap_01} to the root file. If I use cmd-T in the chapter file, the chapter file gets typesetted instead of the root file.

Welcome to TeX.SE! What does doesnt work mean? Please explain better!

I added the magic command to the kap_01.tex (chapter) and \include{chapter/kap_01} to the root file. If I use cmd-T in the chapter file, the chapter file gets typesetted instead of the root file.

What error message do you get? This is important.

l.3 \chapter{Theory of 2D IR} ?. But it works if I just typeset the main root.
